# Error with path and Controller in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my application,i have 1-n relation between Users and Questions,1-n relation between Questions and Answers,and 1-n relation between Users and Questions.
My routes:

```html
 question_answers GET    /questions/:question_id/answers(.:format)          answers#index
                         POST   /questions/:question_id/answers(.:format)          answers#create
     new_question_answer GET    /questions/:question_id/answers/new(.:format)      answers#new
    edit_question_answer GET    /questions/:question_id/answers/:id/edit(.:format) answers#edit
         question_answer GET    /questions/:question_id/answers/:id(.:format)      answers#show
                         PATCH  /questions/:question_id/answers/:id(.:format)      answers#update
                         PUT    /questions/:question_id/answers/:id(.:format)      answers#update
                         DELETE /questions/:question_id/answers/:id(.:format)      answers#destroy
```

My controller:

```html
class AnswersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!,only: [:edit,:update,:destroy,:new,:create]
  before_action :set_answer, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  respond_to :html

  def index
    @answers = Answer.paginate(page: params[:page])
    #@answers = Answer.all
    respond_with(@answers)
  end

  def show
    respond_with(@answer)
  end

  def new
    @questions=Question.find params[:question_id]
    @answer = Answer.new user: current_user
    respond_with(@answer)
  end
  def create
    @answer = Answer.new(answer_params)
    @answer.save
    respond_with(@answer)
  end
  end
```

And when i run program with this link:http://127.0.0.1:3000/questions/1/answers/new:
I got this error:
undefined method `answers_path'.
So what is my error??I thinh i need change answers_path to questions_answer path but how to do this?
Edit:
My routes:

```html
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :questions do
  resources :answers
  end 
end
```

And when i run this link:http://127.0.0.1:3000/questions/1/answers
i got this error:'nil' is not an ActiveModel-compatible object. It must implement :to_partial_path.

Comment: What are you expecting this line in your `def new` method to do: `respond_with(@answer)`

Comment: Well, `rake routes` actually gives the answer: there is no `answers`_path, try `question_answers`_path instead

Comment: i know that i need try question_answers_path instead answers_path,but how to do that??

Comment: Check the views? `app/views/answers/new.html.erb` probably given the link you posted

Comment: My new.html.erb:<h1>New answer</h1>

<%= render 'form' %>

<%= link_to 'Back', question_answers_path %>

Comment: Remove the `respond_with(@answer)` in your `def new` method. The purpose of the new page is for the user to enter in a answer for a question. And what that line of code is doing is rendering the `answer_path`.

Comment: And you're getting the `nil` error because http://127.0.0.1:3000/questions/1/answers is a post requested URI `POST   /questions/:question_id/answers(.:format)          answers#create` and I don't even see a `create` method in your `Answer Controller`

Comment: I have edited with create method.This code is so long,so i dont want to insert all of its.Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a start, in the routes file you are stating that your answers resources all live within the scope of a parent question, but you are only modelling that within `AnswersController#new` – and even then, the `@answer` object you have created bears no relation to the question object.

At the very least, you should define `@answer` using the `has_many` collection's `build` method, so that it is defined as belonging to the question, e.g.:

```
@answer = @question.answers.build(user: current_user)
```

You should adjust your other controller actions as well, to ensure that the appropriate answer action is scoped at all times to the parent question resource.

You may also need to adjust your `respond_with` calls, so that Rails' form helpers can correctly identify the controller path to set for the form's action. You need to provide the nested resource's parent as well, so that the responders code knows to created a nested URL:

```
respond_with(@question, @answer)
```

Comment: @answer = @question.answers.build(user: current_user)>>>which method should i put it in???In a AnswerController right???but which method??

Comment: "You should adjust your other controller actions as well, to ensure that the appropriate answer action is scoped at all times to the parent question resource.">>>can you explain more it for me????Some examples???I am a newbie with Rails

Comment: When you say in your routes file that your answers are sub resources of questions, that means that all the actions on the answers collection apply only to the answers that belong to the parent questions. So `/questions/1/answers` is handled by `AnswersController#index`, but should only return answers that belong to Question 1. So you would instantiate `@question = Question.find(params[:question_id])`, and `@answers = @question.answers`. You'd then do something similar for all the other methods in the controller.

Comment: You can give some examples for me???I dont know what you meant and what is my solutions???

Comment: Providing examples in a stackoverflow comment box is going to be tricky. This screencast may help you – bear in mind it was written for Rails 2.2 so things have moved on slightly, but the bulk of it should still make sense: http://railscasts.com/episodes/139-nested-resources

Comment: `def index
    @question = Question.find(params[:question_id])
    @answers = @question.answer.paginate(page: params[:page])
    #@answers = Answer.all
    respond_with(@answers)
  end`>>>undefined method `answer' for #<Question

Comment: If each question `has_many` answers, your relationship will be `@question.answers`, not `@question.answer`.

Comment: Thank you.I have fix for new and create methods,but now i still can not fix for index method

Comment: my index.html.erb:`<h1>Listing answers</h1>

<%= will_paginate %>

<ul class="questions">
  <%= render [@question, @answer]%>
</ul>

<%= will_paginate %>`

Comment: `  def index
    @question = Question.find(params[:question_id])
    @answers = @question.answers.paginate(page: params[:page])
    respond_with(@question, @answers)
  end`

Comment: error:'nil' is not an ActiveModel-compatible object. It must implement :to_partial_path.

Comment: I have still error answer_path when i update with this _form.html.erb

Comment: My update method:`  def update
    @question=Question.find(params[:question_id])
    @answer=@question.answers.find(params[:id])
    if current_user == @answer.user
        @answer.update(answer_params)
      end
    respond_with(@question,@answer)
  end`